# PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR: cannot cast type regproc to character varying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

source code:

```
class GpRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(
   :adapter=> "postgresql",
   :database=> "xxx",
   :username=> "xxx",
   :password=> "xxx",
   :host=> "xxx"
)
  def self.query
    sql = "SELECT * FROM  table;"
    result = self.connection.exec_query(sql)
  end
end
```

env:

```
ruby 2.2.1p85
pg (0.18.2)
activerecord (4.2.3)
```

but raised a error when exec `GpRequest.query`:

> gems/activerecord4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:in `async_exec': PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type     regproc to character varying (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

this why, anyone can help me?